# Automatically configure beans in root and dispatcher application context with single annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext, spring-java-config

Let's say I've create a annotation called `@EnableFeauture` which imports a bean configuration class `EnableFeatureConfiguration`. This annotation is typically placed on top of the dispatcher configuration. Must beans like view resolvers etc. belong to that dispatcher config but a few beans really belong to the root context.

How can I define those beans without the need for another annotation? My first thought was to autowire the `WebApplicationContext` and call `context.getParentBeanFactory()` to register beans but I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve my goal. How is this typically done?

---

#### UPDATE

To clarify the problem a bit. I'm working on a project to integrate a template engine with Spring MVC. The project consists of the following categories / parts:

- Configuration
- Annotation e.g. `EnableFeature` (imports configuration)
- View
- ViewResolver
- Template factory

Logically all class categories could exist in the web application context. However, the template factory could be used by other services as well (e-mail, etc.). Services that mostly exist in the root context. So what I'm basically asking is, how can I make the factory available to the root context in a clean way. I would like the configuration required to be as low as possible. As of now the setup only requires one annotation placed on top of the dispatcher configuration class.

Comment: Having a hard time grasping your question. To clarify: 1) The following citation from the Spring ref holds for you _[...] you will typically have a root WebApplicationContext loaded via
Spring’s ContextLoaderListener and a child WebApplicationContext loaded via Spring’s
DispatcherServlet._? 2) You want to bring in additional beans to your child context via an annotation of your own, _some_ of the new beans even to the parent context. If so, how do you want to discriminate? Does the code "in your annotation" contain the logic to decide whether to register a bean in child or parent?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what your are trying to achieve (functional level) ? And on why you think you need a custom annotation to do it ?

Comment: See my updated question. I hope this makes it less confusing

Comment: @Hille I have an `ImportAware` configuration that is imported by using the annotation `@EnableFeature` which configures some beans. One bean however (the template factory) would have a better fit in the root context. But I'm not sure how to achieve that in a clean way.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I hope it's clearer now :)

Comment: @Bart do you have to use pure Spring or Spring Boot is also a possible solution?

Comment: @JakubKubrynski I do not use Spring Boot

Comment: So, you have an annotation to be placed ONLY on a web-related configuration class (where you would presumably get access to the WebApplicationContext) and this class has in it beans that should be registered in the WebApplicationContext and beans that should be registered in the root application context (the parent of WebApplicationContext). And you want a way to define this behavior by placing a single annotation on the web-related configuration class. If so, I think `getParentBeanFactory` is your best bet.

Comment: As for a clean solution, I would take a look at Spring Boot, where conditional bean-related behavior is defined with annotations. They are using [Spring's @Conditional annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) to define various conditions that should define what should happen when a certain condition is met.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thank you for your input. I will have a look at the `@Conditional` approach and how it's used.

Comment: Hm, now that I'm trying out this approach, I'm not so sure it's so straight forward... More specifically, how would you tell Spring not to use the result of a `@Bean` annotated method to register it with the web app context, but with the root app context?!

Comment: I may be mistaking but to achieve what you need you would need to mess up with the internals of Spring. A `@Configuration` class is associated with an app context and beans inside that class will be registered with that app context (this is how Spring works). In your case you want get into this lifecycle and force Spring to register a bean in a `@Configuration` class with a different app context than what it's being associated with the configuration class in the first place.

Comment: If this case, I believe you might need a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` registered with the web app context and manually register those beans you need in root context. Unfortunately, I'm not sure this is a clean way, as you would need to manually register the bean definitions inside `postProcessBeanFactory` method using something like `getParentBeanFactory().registerSingleton()`. But in this case, there are some question marks related to how complex your bean is (does it have dependencies?, is it itself a dependency?, if so, are where are these dependencies - root or web?).

Comment: @AndreiStefan You might be on to something. I'm not afraid to register beans manually as this was what I was planning to do anyway. Using a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` might be the correct way alter bean definitions. I will give this idea a spin later today and report back. If you have any other suggestions please share them with me :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59954/discussion-between-bart-and-andrei-stefan).

Comment: @Bart, I have provided my test code in the chat room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me some time to clearly understand what you want to do and the implications beyond. Finding the root application context from the servlet one would be the easy part, `context.getParentBeanFactory()`, or directly `context.getParent()` gives it immediately in any `ApplicationContextAware` class, or through direct injection of the `ApplicationContext`.

The hard part, is that at the time of initialization of the servlet application context, the root application context has already been refreshed. If I look at what happens in Tomcat :

- at deploy time the root application context is fully initialized and refreshed
- next, at first request for the `DispatcherServlet` the child context is initialized with root context as parent.

That mean that when servlet context is initialized, it is way too late to inject beans in root context : all singleton beans have already been created.

There may be workaround, all with their own flaws :

- register a new Configuration class in parent context and do a new refresh().IMHO, this would be the least bad solution as normally WebApplicationContextes support multiple refresh. The potentials problems are :

  - all other beans must be initialized once without the new beans : the configuration must be tolerant to non existing beans
  - other components (filters, security, DAO, etc.) may already be running, and they have to be thoroughly tested against a *hot context refresh*
- create an intermediate ApplicationContext with current root as parent containing beans that should not go into servlet application context, and then create the servlet application context with this intermediate context as parent.

  - no problem for the root application context that is not even aware of the whole operation
  - but no bean of root context can be injected with any new bean
- register all new beans directly in root context. Ok, all is fine for root initialization, and beans of servlet context will have access to all beans. But if one new bean need to be injected with a bean from servlet context, you will have to to it manually at servlet context initialization, with careful tests (or prayers) that it cannot be used before that ... and you will have some pollution of root context with beans only relevant for the servlet
- use only only root context and an empty servlet context.

  - ok, each bean has access to any other one
  - but it breaks the separation between root and servlet context and adds some pollution to the root context

My conclusion is that having a single piece of configuration for 2 different application contextes is a little against Spring philosophy and I would advice you to keep with 2 separate configuration classes one for the root context and one for the servlet context. But if you wish, I can elaborate on the refreshing of root context from servlet context (1st solution).

If you want to inject beans into root context from a *feature* that would be declared in servlet context to have a single configuration point, you can use something like:

```
@Configuration
public class FeatureConfig implements ApplicationContextAware {
    static boolean needInit = true;

    @Override
    // Register the configuration class into parent context and refreshes all
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext parent = 
                (AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext) ((AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext) ac).getParent();
        if (needInit) { // ensure only one refresh
            needInit = false;
            parent.register(RootConfig.class);
            parent.refresh();
            ((AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext) ac).refresh();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Conditional(NoParentContext.class)
    // Can only be registered in root context
    public static class RootConfig {
        // configuration to be injected in root context ...
    }

    // special condition that the context is root
    public static class NoParentContext implements Condition {

        @Override
        public boolean matches(ConditionContext cc, AnnotatedTypeMetadata atm) {
            logger.debug(" {} parent {}", cc.getBeanFactory(), cc.getBeanFactory().getParentBeanFactory());
            return (cc.getBeanFactory().getParentBeanFactory() == null);
        }
    }

    // other beans or configuration that normally goes in servlet context
}
```

With such a `@Configuration` class it is enough to have a `@import(FeatureConfig.class)` annotation in a configuration class for the application context of the `DispatcherServlet`.

But I could not find any way to allow the configuration to happen before the normal servlet application context initialisation. An outcome is that any bean from the special configuration can only be injected in root context with a `@Autowired(required=false)`, because the root context will be refreshed twice, first time without the special configuration class, second time with it.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that it's more trouble then it's worth to try and modify the root context. Your comment however on the `@Conditional` annotation gave me some direction and I love the flexibility. I now allow a bean using `@Bean` to be added to the root config and let the servlet config conditionally configure it's own instance. If you could expand on `@Conditional` in your answer as well I may accept it as the answer if no better solution comes along (which I doubt will happen). [Here is a gist of my current solution](https://gist.github.com/btegenbosch/4e75449e4dc79e03a4e0).

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Bart : I may have another solution using Java configuration. I hope I can elaborate on it in a couple of days (including details on `@Conditional` usage)

Comment: Cool! So the `needIt` part will prevent multiple registration and keeping the contexts out of a continuous refreshing loop. I will play around with this idea as soon as I get the change. Enjoy the bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand all you have to do is to provide custom configuration that will be imported by annotating `@Configuration` class by `@EnableFeature`. Then you just have to include custom beans in your `EnableFeatureConfiguration` class.

```
@Configuration
public class EnableFeatureConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public MyBean myBean() {
    return MyBean();
  }
}
```

Then your `EnableFeature` looks like:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import(EnableFeatureConfiguration.class)
public @interface EnableFeature {
}
```

And that's all. In project you have to use:

```
@Configuration
@EnableFeature
public class MySpringConfig {
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing right now. The problem is that the annotation typically gets placed on top of the web application context configuration (as it should). What I'm looking for is a solution to place a particular bean in the root context instead. Making it available to services in that root context.

Comment: @Bart will it be some public framework project or just custom solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but it will be a public solution. Not sure if I can call it a framework :)